# Is there a way to add untracked files in git when adding via patch?

Tags: git, patch, git-untracked

So I'm learning the joys of `git add -p`. I used to use Sourcetree or similar GUI tool to review changes as part of `git add`, but now I'm getting better with it on the command line.

However, I'm frustrated that I can't add the untracked files in the same command. I'd like it if there was some option like: `git add -p --include-untracked` that then treats them as a patch like the rest of it.

Is there a better way to do this as a single command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of an option to do this directly, seems like a missing feature. Here's some work arounds.

You can run `git add --intent-to-add .` or `-N` before to track all untracked files. This won't add their contents and their changes will show up in `git add -p`. You can add this as an alias in your `.gitconfig`.

```
[alias]
    addp = !git add -N . && git add -p
```

You can use interactive mode, `git add -i`, to get finer control, including adding untracked files.

```
$ git add -i

*** Commands ***
  1: status       2: update       3: revert       4: add untracked
  5: patch        6: diff         7: quit         8: help
What now> 4
  1: foo
Add untracked>> 1
* 1: foo
Add untracked>> ^D
added 1 path

*** Commands ***
  1: status       2: update       3: revert       4: add untracked
  5: patch        6: diff         7: quit         8: help
What now> ^D
Bye.

$ git status
On branch master

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   foo
```

Comment: Amazing ! I use Git for many years now and I encountered the same problem not later than yesterday. Considering what you exposed here, I'll say we no longer lack a new feature, but simply the send of patch to the development team that just appends a note to existing message : "to add a new file by patch, please use git -N first".

Comment: @Obsidian If you're sending patch files around [Git has a robust system for dealing with patches files](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-C%3A-Git-Commands-Email). But patch files are awkward and lose a lot of the power of Git. Instead consider using Git remotes. "*Hey dev team, here's a URL to my repository and my work is in branch `feature`.*" Then they can `git remote add obsidian <url>` and `git fetch obsidian` and merge `obsidian/feature` like any other branch.

Comment: Many thanks once again for these precisions. Of course, when I said "sending a patch", it was in a global sense. I used these commands for Linux Kernel's patch submissions (especially while taking the Eudyptula project) and do pull requests for other projects. But I upvote anyway because these informations remain useful for everyone.

Comment: That `addp` alias is the perfect solution. It's just too bad it's not the default. I can't imagine a case where I wouldn't want to add new files. I guess if I'm starting off and haven't done my `.gitignore` bits correctly yet. But otherwise, in normal code flow, new files and changed files are all part of the work I want to stage, 99% of the time. So now I'm just retraining my brain to do `git addp` and I'm all good